# optional SSRS parameter

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, option-type

I have an optional string parameter @PString and an optional integer parameter @PInt and have the it set up to allow nulls. Can someone help me with the syntax in the "where" clause to consider that parameter if populated else do not consider it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wouldn't it simply be

```
where
(isnull(@Pstring,'')='' or @Pstring = sometable.somecharcolumn)
and
(isnull(@Pint,0)=0 or @Pint = sometable.someintcolumn)
```

you could also do this

```
 where
    (@Pstring is null or @Pstring = sometable.somecharcolumn)
    and
    (@Pint is null or @Pint = sometable.someintcolumn)
```